# Why is this answer a bad post?

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I reviewed this [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/18838455), and I thought it gave a solution to solve the issue in OP and looked OK, so I reviewed it as "No Action Needed", but it turned out to be an audit of a bad post.

Why is it a bad post? Someone commented and said it is a link-only answer, but the answer stated the solution in itself, and is also complete if the links are removed. Of course it is not very good due to lack of detailed explanation, but is it so bad to be a review audit?

**Edit:** P.S. My review privileges were suspended because of this review. If my "No Action Needed" review is acceptable, could moderators please lift or shorten my review ban?

For those who cannot see the post through my link, I paste it as well as the question here.

## Answer

> Assuming you're using the HTML view of the WYSIWYG, rather use the Develop tab in the BC back-end to edit HTML. Also, if you are using the old WYSIWYG, try updating it to the new version in your Partner Portal.
>
> While the Develop tab is sufficient, using a text editor and SFTP client, such as [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com) and [Sublime SFTP](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp), is a great idea.

## Question

> I'm having formatting / rewriting issues with a website I'm editing using Business Catalyst with Adobe.
>
> Everytime I populat a field with an icon, for example;
>
> ```
> <div class="triangle left"><i class="icon-beaker"></i></div>
> ```
>
> I save the file with their admin panel and it converts the icon class to em
>
> So end result is
>
> ```
> <div class="triangle left"><em class="icon-beaker"></em></div>
> ```
>
> This removes the icon entirely

Comment: FYI the original low quality review for the answer received 4 recommend deletion and 2 looks ok..

Comment: If anything, it isn't a link only answer. Those links seems supportive in the answer, if we assume the OP is not affiliated with the products they link.

Comment: Audits check if the reviewer is paying enough attention to the flag.  If you are going to reject a flag then you have to be sure, flaggers invariably know more about what is wrong with a post since they visit the [tag] every day.  Not noticing that the post was deleted a week ago is the standard way to fail an audit.  It is easy to see, the post isn't there.  You have to look.

Comment: *"P.S. My review privileges were suspended because of this review"* . - **false**. It was suspended because of several failed reviews, not just this one.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That is not a bad post. We've deleted value.

The answer is deleted in error by the reviewers. Maybe they got confused by the compact writing style and/or the links in the answer for being spam but the OP doesn't seem to be affiliated with any of the products mentioned.

I gave that answer an edit and an undelete vote.

In my opinion this failed audit should not be held against you but that is something between you and the moderators.

Comment: The editor recommendations are a little unnecessary, but it's definitely an answer.

Comment: I've taken a stab at making the recommendations non-product specific.

Comment: @rene: "we've deleted value": FYI: 1) The post has 1 downvote, and 2) someone edited out the links to the editors. now it looks like crap. IMHO the last edit should be rolled back and the question upvoted.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The someone isn't exactly hiding. I posted a comment just above yours accounting for my action. (Actually I did not just remove  the links, I made it a more general recommendation). You surely know already that you're free to rollback, and everybody knows they're free to upvote, so go right ahead with whatever steps you feel necessary to make things better :) That's all I was doing my with edit.

Comment: yeah, I saw your comment after that. But my rule is "don't undo someone's work without discussion with others first". So I'll leave it like this.

Comment: @StephenKennedy I was torn on what to do when I initial edited. I considered something like *I'm using ...*  or *... for example ...* but felt it would deviate and/or put words in the mouth of the OP that aren't theirs. I'm impartial about your edit but YMMV as you already noticed.